# Are flags on meta reviewed or dealt with?

Tags: support, moderation, flagging, meta

There is a user who has been abusing me regularly on meta. I have flagged their posts multiple times, but all flags are showing as "pending". Are flags on meta reviewed by anyone?

Comment: This is purely anecdotal, hence I'm only making it a comment, but in my six years on Politics.SE I've raised 64 flags on Meta and 63 have been reviewed (the 64th was raised nine hours ago). I can't say why yours haven't been reviewed, but if they were raised within a similar time period (i.e. the last nine hours), then I'd assume the mods simply haven't gotten round to handling them yet.

Comment: FWIW, the mod console for the main site is completely separate from the mod console on Meta. There's one link to let you know there's flags on Meta, but that's it. It can be easy to miss Meta flags as a result.

Comment: The oldest flag I raised 11 days ago, still "pending"

Comment: If they're trying to decide whether to suspend a user over borderline but not clear violations, it can take a while for them to decide "enough is enough". I was myself trolled relatively recently on the mainspace by a certain user who did get suspended eventually. I didn't ask for an outcome like that, but I did flag some of their repeated jabs. And answered in jest a few trying to defuse the situation, hoping that user sees I'm not riled so they give up, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I admit that we neglected the mod queue on meta in the past weeks. The site is currently extremely stressful to moderate (like every time shit happens in Israel), and we moderators prioritize the main site over the meta-site. So we had quite a lot of backlog of flags on meta.

But I now took the time to process the moderation queue for meta. All flags should be processed now. Except for one "very low quality" flag that can and should be handled by regular users via [the review queue](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/review).

Comment: Which queue would that be in? All I see are close, reopen and suggested edits?

Comment: @JoeW The flag is on a question, so it should be in the "close votes" queue. The reason why you don't see it is probably because you implicitly approved that flag when you flagged the same question as a duplicate.